# Как использовать связку OpenCL 2.2 и SPIR-v 1.2

Tags: c++, opencl

Написал небольшую программу на C++ с файлом CL на C, всё работает. В новых версиях OpenCL они допускают использование C++ в файлах CL. Но для этого необходимо еще установить SPIR-V. Как именно его установить, чтобы всё заработало? Единственное, где упоминается об этом всём, это на github'e. Но я так и не нашел четкой инструкции по установки данной связке. От OpenCL мы используем лишь библиотеку, а что необходимо для SPIR-V?
У кого есть опыт работы с данными технологиями, поделитесь небольшими знаниями пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL 2.0, 2.1, 2.2 не работает ни на одной из NVidia независимо от установки SPIR-V. Для OpenCL 2.0 у посл. драйверов NVidia есть только частичная поддержка, скажем, pipes работать не будут. В полной мере для NVidia реализована только поддержка OpenCL 1.2, т.е. язык C99 для Kernel, а не С++12. Для AMD можно для посл. видеокарт найти драйверы с полной поддержкой OpenCL 2.0-2.1. Про поддержку Intel ничего не скажу.